# Extending Asp.NET MVC3 Controller Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a fairly experienced .NET programmer, as well as a MVC programmer with PHP. Now I'm new at MVC3 and trying to build my first work on it, so I'm dealing with a few questions. For starters, how do I extend the Controller Class? Can someone point me to a guide/list of methods I should implement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to implement any methods to extend the controller, although obviously it would be rather silly not to.  You just inherit from it, and override the methods you wish to alter.

If you don't know what methods to alter, I have to question why you want to extend it?

EDIT:

You may benefit from the two big MVC sample applications, Nerddiner and Music Store.  They give you a very good idea of how to make ecommerce sites and the like in MVC.  Don't take them as gospel, because they are samples and are intended to be simple.  They don't currently make use of best practices like Dependency Injection, or Repository design.  Some links to useful tutorials:

[Lots of good videos here.  The Pluralsight stuff is pretty straight forward](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

[The Music Store tutorial app](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1)

[NerdDinner tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials#NerdDinner)

Comment: With web forms I always had BasePage class extending System.Web.UI.Page, in which I wrote some properties, constants and virtual methods and overrided methods such as OnPreInit, to do something before the other Page classes were loaded. I'm trying to figure how to get such a behaviour from Controllers.

Comment: @nosuchnick - MVC is very different from Webforms.  You don't generally override anything in the pipeline because you don't have all the stupid hooks for the control system.  You pretty much do all you work in an Action method, and do all your formatting in the view.  Things like constants are probably better off in static utility classes.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But even in PHP, with MVC framework codeigniter, i use a base controller to handle cross site basic stuff, like logged user.

Comment: @nosuchnick - Logged in user is already handled by the framework, if you're using Memebership (which you should be).  I'm not saying there is no need to override a base class, but it's a lot less frequent than most people used to need it.  You can always extend the controller class, and use your extension.  But it's very straight forward.  You only have to add whatever you want to add, nothing special.

Comment: @Mystere Man - Ok, I'll check Membership later, by now I was using that as an example. Let's say I've got two roles of users and the menu should be loaded according to the role logged in. My approach would be to check the role before anything else and load the respective menu View. And I dont want to do that in every controller action, I want it to be done by default for every controller action. This is only an example, I can think of dozens like that. Shopping carts, style preferences, even loading constants from webconfig.

Comment: @nosuchnick - In the case of the menu, that will most likely go in the master page, as will most shopping cart items.  Most things you want to use across your site like that are likely to be good candidates for a single implementation in the master pager.

Comment: @Mystere Man - Ah! But from what I've seen and read so far, I think the masterpage is the view _Layout, which is mostly html and didn't seem to have a controller file. Ok, I really need to get a book on this. If I add a masterpage, it is aspx. And I should be using razor.

Comment: @nosuchnick - You didn't say if you were using Razor or not, but since you are, it's called a Layout page, rather than a master page.  Still, you can do the same kinds of things.  You don't have code behinds, but you can put code in the Layout page, for example to choose to display a "Login" link or a current user.  This code should be as minimal as possible, with nothing much more than an if statement.  If you need to do more work, then create a service class to handle it, and have that service class return the data you need.

Comment: @Mystere Man - I'm using razor as I have some time for this project, so I thought I should try to learn some new stuff. I'm now going to read about service classes, I wasn't aware of them. My biggest trouble so far, and I've only been around asp.net mvc for 8 hours, is to re-think the code organization, as it is way too different (for the better, I hope) from the aspx web forms I was used to. About the examples you provided, I was already following the Music Store, I'll check on the others. Thank you ;)

Comment: @nosuchnick - Well, Music Store should give you most of what you're looking for. Service classes isn't really a "thing" per se, it's just more of a terminology. It's when you abstract code into it's own unit (useful for unit testing, but also useful as a way to make your code more maintainable). If you create a new project and use the default project template, then it includes a MembershipService, which just abscracts the membership API into its own class. service classes take code, for instance business logic, and create an API for it rather than embedding it into the code behind.

Comment: @Mystere Man - Update: I've finished the Music Store and yes, lots of questions are answered by now. About Membership, I'm not sure it fits. It seems to create a table for all users, and I prefer having one for admin users (with diferent roles) and another for site Clients. Also, it creates its own database with own tables I cant seem to modify. But I'm sure I'll find a way around it without creating the Base Controller I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @nosuchnick - While you may have your own preferences, in the long run you'll be a lot happier if you use the membership system, just because it's so well integrated into everything.  You can do your own custom stuff, but it's a lot more work.  You can configure the system to use whatever database you wish (in web.config), but the default membership does have its own tables (you don't want to modify them.  If you need more data just create another table that uses the userid as it's primary key).

Comment: @Mystere Man - It might work that way... I come from a company where we wrote everything from scratch (hey, i'm not saying it was a good practice) but i was used to write my tables, sql, classes, security, etc. So now i'm working on my own and trying to get up to date but when things sound too easy i get in doubt thinking "oh maybe i should write a stored procedure for that and do things the old way". I'm sure experimentation will help me figure what to use and where :)

Comment: EDIT - by now i'm still astonished how entity framework/code first designs beautiful foreign-key related tables in the database. I'm having some trouble, though, updating the database whenever I add or modify a model.

Comment: Who marked this as answer. You have just pointed to mvc tutorials out there. How is that answering the question. Down voting for the same.

Comment: @gauravvgat - I did not just point to the MVC tutorials.  I pointed to them in addition to answering the question.  The question was what methods had to be implemented to extend the controller, and the answer, as I correctly answered.. is none.

Comment: That clears things. Guess I was confused initially.Can you edit the answer, so that I can upvote. I am not able to undo down vote.

Comment: @gauravvgat - there you go.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement anything, just make your class inherit from System.Web.Mvc.Controller. Normally there is no real benefit to doing this, but in some cases it can be helpful make some form of common custom base controller class that all controllers in your project could share.

Beware though, when adding common methods to your controllers. It often makes more sense to add these methods to some lower tier of your application, or as helpers methods on your models or viewmodels.

Comment: Thanks... please read my comment to previous answer in which I explain myself a little better.

Comment: Yeah, well, I stand by my answer. In my experience there is very little benefit to using a custom base controller. For authentication and logging users and whatnot, you could make custom actionfilters though. Controllers should really just be actionhandlers, and they should be as slim as possible. See this presentation: http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/1/ (it's for MVC2 but all the points are still valid for MVC3. Despite the lousy recording, it is really good)

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this, so I'm sure I'll learn something.