# MVC3 - Helper method to be used by several controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to have a method returning `ActionResult`, that has access to `Response`/`Json` and other things controllers have access to and use it from multiple controllers.

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example of what exactly you're after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider making a base controller class and inheriting from that.  This allows you to use the same method from multiple controllers.

I'm not sure of your experience level with MVC, but [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269(v=vs.100).aspx) article from Microsoft gives the basic foundations of ideas behind the controller and what you can do with it.  And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171306/extending-asp-net-mvc3-controller-class) question points to some well accepted examples of an MVC app.

Comment: I didn't think of inheriting, I thought I could add it as a helper of some sort. That's a nice solution, thanks

Comment: FYI, the first link is orphaned now.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge thanks.  Pointed it to possibly the oldest link on Controllers, but pertinent none the less.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on the learning curve, so it's definitely useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Extending from what Nick has already pointed out here is a really silly example. Note, the HomeController inheriting from BaseController. The SomeResult action will be available within the HomeController.

For demonstration purposes only here is a ViewModel:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The Base Controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeResult()
    {
        var customer = new Customer { Name = "Jon", Age = 15 };
        return Json(customer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The Home Controller inheriting from the base controller:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```